# iOS Shortcut icon not showing up when shared to watch

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, ios-shortcut

I'm finishing up an app extension that provides shortcut support. Shortcuts are working great, and the app's icon shows up in the shortcut on the iPhone.

The problem is that the icon doesn't bubble up to the watch. I get the generic developer icon instead.

- Assets file created with name "Assets-Shortcuts" Assets file has an
  icon group called "AppIcon-Extension"
- Project settings has
  "AppIcon-Extension" set for the extension's icon.
- After I set up the
  assets file, Xcode then started showing the icon in the target list
  for the extension, so Xcode seems to think I did it right.
- Build
  Phases shows the assets file under "Copy Bundle Resources".

When you create the shortcut, the app's extension icon is properly displayed in the shortcut.
After sharing it to the watch, the shortcut is shared properly, but has a generic developer icon.

I'm stumped as to what to do. Any ideas? I even tried Apple Watch icons in both the app's assets file and the extension's assets file with no luck.